# How do I count total of row in mysql without get Fatal error : Allowed memory

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 141954624 bytes)` when to count all of row mysql table

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$count = $db->num_rows($query);

echo $count;
```

Total rows about 17k and I got `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 141954624 bytes)`. Let me know, how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change your SQL query to...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `rows_count` FROM `table`;
```

Then you don't have to load such a large recordset to just then use a row counting function to get the number of rows.

Comment: +1 for being faster than me. Friendly suggestion: avoid using reserved words as colum aliases.

Comment: @Asaph Whoops, I didn't even realise I had done that :) Thanks.

Comment: @alex: Thanks for changing it. It would have worked fine the way you had it originally since you surrounded the column alias with backticks. But this is better.

Comment: @Asaph No worries. Is there a way to do it without mentioning the `id` column and without using `*` ?

Comment: @alex: Not that I am aware of. Referencing the primary key is the preferred approach. I imagine the MySQL development team can optimize count(*) queries to be virtually the same. But I don't know if they've actually done it.